# knockout js text bind giving object instead of string in magento2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am binding knockout js value to html but it's give me

**[object HTMLLIElement]**

insteadof value

```
  prescriptionList:{customer_prescription_id: "1", customer_id: "23971", customer_name: "Rutvee Sojitra", customer_email: "rutvee.sojitra@krishtechnolabs1.com", prescription: "This is some Description for this product option", …}
enter code here



     <td class="col col-method" data-bind ="foreach: prescriptionList()">
                            <span data-bind="text: prescription"></span>
```

Comment: Have you tried html instead of text <span data-bind="html: prescription"></span> ?

Comment: i have already try with this but no luck

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :) +1 from mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below code in your html :

```
<td class="col col-method">
<!-- ko foreach: prescriptionList -->
    <span data-bind="text: prescription"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
</td>
```

Make sure that your array length should be available.

Refresh your html file in a browser and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,without foreach

```
prescriptionList:{customer_prescription_id: "1", customer_id: "23971", customer_name: "Rutvee Sojitra", customer_email: "rutvee.sojitra@krishtechnolabs1.com", prescription: "This is some Description for this product option", …}
enter code here

<td class="col col-method">
<span data-bind="text:prescriptionList().prescription"></span>
```